# Can't access windows 10 when BIOS is in legacy mode

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, multi-boot, bootloader, easybcd

I was trying to add Ubuntu to the boot loader by using EasyBCD but realised I could only add an entry if I set legacy mode on in my BIOS. But when I rebooted I couldn't boot to windows 10.

**Helpful comment:**

```
Your Windows 10 boot disk might be formatted GPT which would require non-
legacy UEFI to boot, if I'm not mistaken. Legacy mode doesn't understand GPT. – LawrenceC
```

Comment: What happened when you tried to boot into Windows 10.

Comment: It tried to do a network boot.

Comment: Your Windows 10 boot disk might be formatted GPT which would require non-legacy UEFI to boot, if I'm not mistaken.  Legacy mode doesn't understand GPT.